# Is it possible to segue from a MapView callout button

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, mkmapview, segue

I have been stuck on this issue for ages now, is it possible to have a segue between view controllers when touching a callout button in Swift/Xcode 7. I have created the MapView and the annotations + callouts and button on the call out but I am having trubble segueing the buton with another view. Is it possible and if so, how is it done?

Comment: In Objective C there is a function -> " -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control" you can use this function and call "performSegueWithIdentifier" in this function and then you can go another view in "prepareForSegue"

Comment: is there a way to do this in swift? @alitsnr

Comment: Search how to call 'void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)' in swift and use prepareForSegue